# AS3: what does Z do? How to have DEPTH?

Tags: actionscript-3, layer, perspective, depth

Scenario:

The more Y value, the more "in front" a movie clip is.

So if I have two movie clips.

```
Movieclip1.y is 50
Movieclip2.y is 20
```

Then movieclip1 should be infront of movieclip2.

If

```
movieclip1.y = 20
movieclip2.y = 20
movieclip3.y = 56
movieclip4.y = 921
```

then

movieclip4 should be most in front
movieclip3 should be second most in front
and the two others should be on equal depth

something like

```
this.z = this.y?
```

But I have no idea how the code is.

Comment: You're thinking of z-index: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865426/arrange-z-order-of-objects-in-flash-with-actionscript-3

Comment: @adaam It's not called `z-index` in as3.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet Apologies - it's been quite a while since I programmed in AS3!

Comment: @adaam Yeah, I only code in as3 because I make apps and it's an easy code language, but I got most of the knowledge from JavaScript.

Comment: I've re-read the question. Are you saying that the value of the y-position of the clip should affect the depth of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can layer them using [`addChild`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild%28%29):

```
this.addChild(movieclip1);
this.addChild(movieclip2); // is stacked above movieclip1;
```

And you can use the [`setChildIndex`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#setChildIndex%28%29) method to change the order:

```
this.setChildIndex(movieclip1, 1);
this.setChildIndex(movieclip2, 0); // switch the depths
```

Comment: but if I want them to change the z-axis depending on where they move? 

so it isn't like this forever, so that sometimes movieclip 1 can go in front of movieclip 4 etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet I made that changes the MovieClip's depth according to it's z value (pseudo code, you might have to edit this a bit):

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeDepth);

function changeDepth():void
{
    var movs = [movieclip1, movieclip2];
    var movsVal = [movieclip1.z, movieclip2.z];
    var a = movsVal.indexOf(Math.max.apply(movsVal));
    if(movs.indexOf(a) === 0)
    {
        swapChildren(a, movs[movsVal.indexOf(a) + 1])
    }else
    {
        if(movs.indexOf(a) === 1)
        {
            swapChildren(a, movs[movsVal.indexOf(a) - 1])
        }
    }
    movs = [movieclip3, movieclip4];
    movsVal = [movieclip3.z, movieclip4.z];
    a = movsVal.indexOf(Math.max.apply(movsVal));
    if(movs.indexOf(a) === 2)
    {
        swapChildren(a, movs[movsVal.indexOf(a) + 1])
    }else
    {
        if(movs.indexOf(a) === 3)
        {
            swapChildren(a, movs[movsVal.indexOf(a) - 1])
        }
    }
}
```

Basically check the largest `z` (3d coordinate) and swap it with whatever's behind it.